# Mongodb, sharding and horizontal scaling

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb, i want to use mongos and do mongodb sharding over 2 machines, is it common to have a single collection and adding an documents to my collections such as :

```
{type:'user',name:'xxx',id:1,.........}
{type:'userentery',userid:1.........}
{type:'usersettings',userid:1.......} 
{type:'userevent',userid:1.......}
{type:'SomthingNotRelated',....}
```

- is my understanding correct to how you should use mongodb?
- and is the the way to do horizontal scaling and avoid vertical scaling by
  avoiding adding more collections?
- what are the disadvantages of my approach?
- if a user had a very big array wouldn't it be better putting it in a
  seperate document rather than the user document itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"shredding" no such word for MongoDB. It is "sharding", since you cannot get the name right I would strongly suggest you read the documentation right here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding/

> is my understanding correct to how you should use mongodb?

From what I understand yes.

> and is the the way to do horizontal scaling and avoid vertical scaling by avoiding adding more collections?

More or less. Sometimes an aggregate collection of another, containing unique entries or summed entries is also helpful for scaling.

> what are the disadvantages of my approach?

You haven't really described a specific approach to anything as such I cannot answer that.

> if a user had a very big array wouldn't it be better putting it in a seperate document rather than the user document itself?

Depends on the operations of that array. If the array were to be consistently and continiously updated so that it would dramatically shift in size regularly then yes, you would be better splitting it off.

Such subdocuments are normally actually separate entities in themselves when thought of logically.

Comment: I made a typo, you don't have to be so rude, it was just a minor mistake due to I was writing in a rush.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios Huh? I was talking to the OP, also I wasn't rude, I suggested that since the name couldn't be written right it is highly likely that ones knowledge could also be flawed, as such it would be good to read the documentation

Comment: I don't think we all don't understand anything, sometimes a typo is just a mistake. The concept was there and it was clear we understood what we were talking about.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios there is a difference between lack of knowledge and not knowing everything. If you ask me, as someone who is well seasoned with sharding I would say that the question was not well prepared personally however hopefully the OP has got the resources he requires to clear up the confusion he has about how sharding actually works.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios also it is quite a typo to be in both the title and the body of the question

Comment: Ok, you're right, we don't know anything about it, end of discussion

Answer (score 1):

Sharding is the ability of Mongo to split a single collection (any collection) in shards (pieces of the collection) into different small databases (to make it simple). For you it's completely transparent, you use a collection "colX" sharded and you can split it into several machines if you want. The only recommendation is you have to be smart enough and read the documentation to use a proper shard key that helps you to split in the best balanced way possible your collection.
You can use your collection and in case this type is statistically relevant to represent a good balance in the collection (it means if you have 10 million records and 10 types it's normal you have around 1 million each) you can use it and shard by type.

Your approach is correct, you just need to use the correct shard key.

One more comment added to my note. A wrong shard key won't accelerate your process too much, if you query by type and your shard key is type it's faster to get the proper shard to return your information. In the other case, if you need, let's say to query by date and it's not in your shard key, Mongo will need to send your query to every shard and merge the result at the end. Sharding help you a lot in some cases and not too much in some other cases, of course you duplicate processor and it's always better but you won't see a big difference always if you didn't choose your shard key properly.

Comment: i will be using dates very often in my queries, and for sure type will be my shredding key, but querying by data is limited to 2 types which are 'userevet' and user 'userentery', is that bad and would you put each of those in a seperate collection?

Comment: It's **sharding**, not shredding.

Comment: You're right, sharding, if you see my post I said sharding and shredding in different parts of the text :)

Comment: Composite keys are ok but they must ensure a good cardinality. For example, the maximum cardinality always is _id due to this key is unique and it ensures |collection| = N always. In the other case Mongo cannot balance the shards correctly, you will end up with a bunch of data in some shards. If you use dates often AND date has a good cardinality (you're entering for example transactions of an e-commerce website and you have a fair amount of sales everyday) you can use date in your shard key. User entry, not sure what it is.

Comment: @Kanka I would not use dates with your type field, it will result in hotspots on the latest shard upon write. The cardinality of type (i.e. 2 types) measn that you must parent index by either them, limiting the number of chunks you can do or by time creating a hotspot

Comment: Well, in my case I have a datetime but not represented by an ISODate, as a string, and it ensures cardinality in one of my collections. It could work but it's not always a solution.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios indeed date is very cradinal, but it is also monotonic

Comment: I didn't find any information in Mongo (unless you know the internal algorithm) that mentions anything about downsides of shard keys represented by monotonic functions. What's the exact issue about it?

Comment: @MaximilianoRios distribution of data, MongoDB Docs have made it stupidly vague by puiting it here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/#create-a-shard-key-that-has-high-degree-of-randomness

Comment: I read the documentation more than once but I don't see the problem of using a monotonic function. Unless MongoDB is not smart enough to distribute data with the internal algoritm in the process of splitting.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios MongoDBs sharding works upon ranges